# Count even numbers in a file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function that takes as argument, a filename to read, returns the number of even numbers present in the file.

I have tried and tried please some one help. it does not return the the even numbers.

```
def counteven(l):
    infile = open('even.txt', 'r')
    num = infile.read()
    for i in infile:
        if (i %2!=0):
            return i

    infile.close()

assertEqual(counteven('even.txt'),2)
```

Answer (score 3):

@Ergwun [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657154/can-any-one-figure-this-out-using-python/5657367#5657367) already the problems in your code. Here's another solution:

```
def counteven(integers):
    return sum(1 for n in integers if n % 2 == 0)

with open('even.txt') as f:
    numbers = (int(line) for line in f)
    print(counteven(numbers))
```

Comment: JF your solution works to print bt its not working for the assertequals.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what the format of the file is. Based on your attempt, I'm assuming that your file contains just a single integer on each line.

Here are some of the problems with your function:

- You are passing an argument to the function called `l`, but not using it. You should be using it as the name of the file to open, instead of hard coding `'even.txt'`.
- You are reading the entire file into a variable called `num` and then do not even use that variable. Having read in the entire file, there is nothing left to iterate over in your for loop.
- Your `for` loop iterates over the lines of the file as strings. You need to convert the line to an integer before testing if it's divisible by two.
- Inside the `for` loop, you are going to return the first even number found, rather than counting all the even numbers. You need to create a count variable before the loop, and increment in the loop every time an even number is found, then return the count after the loop has completed.

If you fix those problems, your function should look something like this:

```
def counteven(filename):
  countOfEvenNumbers = 0
  infile = open(filename, 'r')
  for line in infile:
    number = int(line)
    if (number %2 == 0):
      countOfEvenNumbers+= 1
  infile.close()
  return countOfEvenNumbers
```

...

**UPDATE** (to address your comment):

`assertEqual` is a method of the `TestCase` class provided by the `unittest` module.
If you are writing a unit test, then `assertEqual` should be called in a test case in a class derived from `TestCase`.

If you simply want to make an assertion ouside of a unit test you can write:

```
assert counteven('even.txt') == 2, ' Number of even numbers must be 2'
```

Comment: hi i have tried doing it before the way Ergwun suggested and the assertEquals is not working properly and i jst copied and pasted Ergwun's solutions the assertEqual still not working jst like how i initially did mine.

Comment: Minor point: any non-integer characters will throw a ValueError on 'number = int(line)', could be prevented with a try...except

Comment: Yeah, this solution assumes a file containing a single integer on each line. I've omitted error checking etc. for brevity and clarity when relating to code in the question, but it would be improved by your suggestion.